# package_search query parameters includes both keywords and tags

Tags: api, data.gov, ckan

When I queried a data catalog using GUI

https://data.noaa.gov/dataset/?q=fish&tags=California&sort=score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc

it fetched 42 records.

I wanted to implement the same query through API using package_search function. While I was successful either using keywords or tags alone for my other query cases, I was not successful for this particular one that involved a combination of keywords and tags.

For example, the query

https://data.noaa.gov/dataset/api/3/action/package_search?q=fish&q=tags:California&rows=1000

is successful, but fetches zero record, unlike the 42 records through search on the GUI (see the first query).

I have met similar problem with data.gov.

Any suggestion, where did I make a mistake in the API query?

Comment: Finally, I figured out the way to do it. https://data.noaa.gov/dataset/api/3/action/package_search?q=fish+tags:California&rows=1000

Comment: please make this comment an answer to your question.